# Native Queries aren't supported by this value - Snowflake & PowerBi

Tags: sql, powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, powerbi-desktop

The query works perfectly fine in snowflake. But when i'm trying to connect it to Power bi, i get this error. The query has no semi-colons as some other suggestions posted.
Did anyone find a work around?

```
SELECT  a.NUMBER
        ,a.LOB
        ,a.DATE
        ,a.STATE
        ,a.CODE
        ,b.STATUS
        ,b.YEARS
        ,a.RPM
FROM "PD_ANALYST"."SAMPLE"."SAMPLE" as a
LEFT JOIN  "PD_ANALYST2"."SAMPLE"."SAMPLE" as b
ON a.NUMBER = b.NUMBER
WHERE a.LOB IN ('AU','UM','CY')
AND a.STATUS = 'InForce'
```

Comment: this solution (https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/quot-Native-queries-aren-t-supported-by-this-value-quot-When/m-p/2227945/highlight/true) it seems to the ODBC connection needs to be setup

Comment: For some very odd reason, snowflake suspended the warehouse being use. Tried different warehouses and it worked.

Comment: if PowerBI is talking sporadically, it makes sense to have the WAREHOSE have AUTORESUME set to true, so it's not always running, but also can run when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Snowflake nor Amazon redshift supports in Schedule refresh in Power BI Report Server.

[image: Power Bi Report page]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/data-sources